# Laravel 4.2 projects working on xampp/win7 but not on Ubuntu

Tags: php, laravel, ubuntu, virtual-machine, lamp

I have multiple projects in Laravel 4.2 that I would like to get working on my computer with Ubuntu 18.04 os.

Projects work fine on my Win7 pc with xampp that has php version 7.1, all I had to do to get them working there was to disable deprecated errors.

The problem is that I just can't get them to properly work on linux.

I have tried multiple things, like using linux version of xampp, manually installing each component of LAMP and even homestead and vagrant.

If I use PHP version 7.1 or 7.2 on homestead I get the "mcrypt php extension required",but 7.1 works just fine on xampp/win7.

If I use PHP 5.6,7.0 on homestead or LAMP that I've installed myself, I can open the projects but I have a lot of problems with completely rendering views,for example some pages only have navbars,others miss a lot of content etc.
Some pages even throw errors like "Unexpected end of file",even though they work perfectly on xampp/win7 setup.

I thought that linux file permissions might be the cause of the problem, so I played around with chown command,but that did not help.

Another guess I have is that xampp on windows probably has more lenient php and apache settings, but I cant pin point what causes the problems.

I'm aware that a question is a bit broad but I would really apreciate the help, and if you need any other info to answer the question just ask.

Edit:

Modules on xampp/win7
[image]

Modules on LAMP/ubuntu

[image]

Comment: Do a phpinfo() on both systems and compare installed modules

Comment: Here are the [server requirements](https://laravel.com/docs/4.2/installation#server-requirements) for 4.2. Make sure they're met

Comment: +kerbholz Server requirements are met.

Comment: +delboy1978uk I've tried to enable all of the modules that were missing on linux apache and there is no change.

Answer (score 0):

try running cache:clear and view:clear commands

Comment: Thanks for the effort,but that did not help me, there is no difference.